# Scrape Trivago issue

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, urlfetch

I am using following code to scrape web page:

```
$ch =curl_init("http://www.trivago.de/?aDateRange%5Barr%5D=2015-08-07&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D=2015-08-10&iRoomType=7&bIsTotalPrice=false&iPathId=3577&iGeoDistanceItem=1473453&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&");
 $fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But the web page I getting is either incorrect or incomplete to real page.

I am getting this incomplete:

[What I getting by scrape](https://z-1-scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/11846741_10207481741670050_8699688184733056576_n.jpg?oh=b8932d39ed0b601712537384d14e3cea&oe=5678DE6A)

And actual web page is this:
[Actual page](https://z-1-scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/v/t1.0-9/s480x480/11214314_10207481759190488_6315849449132394061_n.jpg?oh=0b3c8a149596a36054e618cc10efe1da&oe=567CBE13)

Answer (score 0):

Your CURL is supposed to look similarly for the task at hand:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://yourwebiste.com');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5); //5 seconds
$result = curl_exec($ch); //$result now holds fetched data
curl_close($ch);
```

The code is part of my own CURL library. Remember you're not fetching file but rather the returned HTML content.

Comment: thanks for your response, I am HTML as I getting before. But not the whole page html data. I am getting this incomplete:                                 https://z-1-scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/11846741_10207481741670050_8699688184733056576_n.jpg?oh=b8932d39ed0b601712537384d14e3cea&oe=5678DE6A                                                And actual web page is this:  https://z-1-scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/v/t1.0-9/s480x480/11214314_10207481759190488_6315849449132394061_n.jpg?oh=0b3c8a149596a36054e618cc10efe1da&oe=567CBE13